# Recalling a value defined value in the title/subtitle for a plot

Tags: plot, title, defined

I'm new to python and I'm using it to analyze some data.  At the bigining of my code I define which data scan ID i'm using as "sid = 238039".  I'd like to also define the scan angle as "angle = 72.500 deg." for the rest of my code.

[Definition of "angle"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHBfn.png)

But when I put "angle" into the text I have from my advisor to lable my figures, the Scan ID is recalled, but "angle" just shows out as "angle" and not the value I defined.

What is the proper syntax to have this recall '73.500 deg.' for the rest of my code in the plots?

[The output for my plots using "angle"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKR52.png)

I'm looking on line, but nothing is jumping out at me.  I'm sure this is an easy fix, I'm just a noob!